# custom property DataGridViewTextBoxColumn not saved

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I need to add a string property to a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`: to do this I've created my custom column:

```
public class MhsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public MhsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
```

and in the columns editor appears correctly:

[image]

but if I press ok and save the column properties, the new property is not saved and each time I open the columns editor the `TableName` property is blank..

is there a simple way to store the custom properties?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are required to override the Clone function in order for that to work:

```
public override object Clone() {
  var column = base.Clone() as MhsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
  if (column != null) {
    column.TableName = this.TableName;
  }
  return column;
}
```